# Can't declare Cursor in class not MainActivity

Tags: android, cursor

I have class control to get data of sms by Cursor, but it was problem when I call ReadSMS in class MainActivity, but I copy all code from ReadSMS to MainActivity and run, it will run normal.

```
public class ReadSMS extends AppCompatActivity {

public ReadSMS() {
}

public TreeMap getListSMS() {
    ArrayList<SMS> listSMS = new ArrayList<>();
    TreeMap<String, ArrayList<SMS>> tm = new TreeMap();
    Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(smsUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (!cur.moveToFirst()) { /* false = cursor is empty */
        return null;
    }

    String temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {
        String _id = cur.getString(0);
        String _thread_id = cur.getString(1);
        temp = _thread_id;
        String _address = cur.getString(2);
        String person = getContactName(getApplicationContext(), _address);
        String date = cur.getString(4);
        String date_send = cur.getString(5);
        String protocol = cur.getString(6);
        String read = cur.getString(7);
        String status = cur.getString(8);
        String type = cur.getString(9);
        String reply_path_present = cur.getString(10);
        String subject = cur.getString(11);
        String body = cur.getString(12);
        String service_center = cur.getString(13);
        String locked = cur.getString(14);
        String error_code = cur.getString(15);
        String seen = cur.getString(16);
        long timeDate = Long.valueOf(date);
        date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm yyyy/MM/dd").format(new Date(timeDate));

        SMS sms = new SMS(_id, _thread_id, _address, person, date, date_send, protocol,
                read, status, type, reply_path_present, subject, body, service_center,
                locked, error_code, seen);


        if (!tm.containsKey(sms.get_thread_id())) {
            listSMS.add(sms);
            tm.put(sms.get_thread_id(), listSMS);
        } else {
            listSMS = tm.get(sms.get_thread_id());
            listSMS.add(sms);
            tm.put(sms.get_thread_id(), listSMS);
        }
        listSMS = new ArrayList<>();
        cur.moveToNext();
    }
    cur.close();

    return tm;
}

public String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return contactName;
}
```

}

It notice problem at line:

```
 Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(smsUri, null, null, null, null);
```

**Update: Mike M.' answer is below solve my problem**

Comment: Which problem u notice at given line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've apparently made `ReadSMS` an `AppCompatActivity` subclass so that the `getContentResolver()` method would resolve in your IDE. This won't work, as you're presumably creating an instance of `ReadSMS` in `MainActivity` with `new`, which you can't do with an `Activity`, as its `Context` will not have been properly created.

If you want to move the query to a separate class, don't make the class a descendent of `Activity`. Instead, pass a `Context` in the `getListSMS()` method that you can call `getContentResolver()` on, like you've done in the `getContactName()` method. You could also then make both methods `static`, so you don't need to create an instance of the class to call the methods.

```
public class ReadSMS {

    public static TreeMap getListSMS(Context context) {
        ...

        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(smsUri,
                                                        null,
                                                        null,
                                                        null,
                                                        null);
        ...
    }

    public static String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, in your `MainActivity`, you would call them like so:

```
Map messages = ReadSMS.getListSMS(MainActivity.this);

...

String name = ReadSMS.getContactName(MainActivity.this, phoneNumber);
```